# Translator: pseudo-code to a concrete language (PHP, JAVA) library suggestion

Tags: java, php, pseudocode, code-translation

I'm building a visual programming tool and was wondering if you could suggest a library or even throw at me ideas about a tool that I can build myself that translates the pseudo-code to a concrete language as PHP, JAVA. For example for a pseudocode like that:

```
do i = 1 to 100 
   print "Hello World !!!";
   newline;
end do
```

I would like to get something similar to:

in **PHP**:

```
for ($i = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    echo "Hello World !!!";
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

in **Java**:

```
for(int i = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
    System.out.print("Hello World !!!");
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

I don't just want a translator from PHP to Java or vise versa.
I guess my question is: Will I be able to generate code in all kinds of languages after specifying some basic language structure rules and writing the pseudo-code? I want to break the gap between the pseudocode and code in a concrete language so I won't need to translate the code by hand. Also by writing the algorithm in pseudocode once, I would generate the code in a whatever language I want.

Thank you for your feedback!

**edit:** ok, so not "pseudo" code then, defining a language that will work as a intermediate. Does any one have a suggested library for that I can look into?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: i dont think you will find a library for this. I have heard of one of my friend who wanted to do a similar thing, he was trying to convert english text to code. And as per him some people are trying to do this.

Comment: @Dagon one reason is defining the algorithm once and then just translating it whatever language I like. Impossible you say, my friend?

Comment: if you know the languages you are translating in to you should write them ,if you don't using something like this is just dangerous. you chose a *for* loop for your *do* in php but there are multiple other options depending on the circumstances, something you will never be able to handle via translation code.

Comment: yes, I understand. Normally it will be me who will be implementing a new language, I would like to be able to manually insert/customize the replacements like the the _for_ you mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of pseudo-code is that it has no definite syntax and no definite semantics.  It is a way for human beings to communicate algorithms to other human beings in a way that avoids the reader and writer having to worry about such details.

That means that it impossible to translate automatically.  Instead, you need a human being to *understand* what the pseudo-code means and then *write* code in a concrete programming language that has the same effect.

---

Another way to look at this is that if "pseudo-code" had defined syntax and semantics, it wouldn't be "pseudo".  It would be *real* code.

Of course, there is nothing stopping you from defining a language of this nature ... but then you'd need to implement compilers and/or translators for *your* pseudo-pseudo-code ( :-) ).

---

> OK, so not "pseudo" code then, defining a language that will work as a intermediate ...

There are various tools that you could use to help you build a source code to source code translator.  Search for "parser generator" and "template engine".